# SQL - Add To Existing Average

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to build a reporting table to track server traffic and popularity overall. Each SID is a unique game server hosting a particular game, and each UCID is a unique player key connecting to that server.

Say I have a table like so:

```
SID  UCID            AvgTime  NumConnects 
-----------------------------------------
1    AIE9348ietjg    300.55   5  
1    Po328gieijge    500.66   7
2    AIE9348ietjg    234.55   3
3    Po328gieijge    1049.88  18
```

We can see that there are 2 unique players, and 3 unique servers, with SID 1 having 2 players that have connected to it at some point in the past. The AvgTime is the average amount of time those players spent on that server (in seconds), and the NumConnects is the size of the average (ie. 300.55 is averaged out of 5 elements).

Now I run a job in the background where I process a raw connection table and pull out player connections like so:

```
SID  UCID            ConnectTime  DisconnectTime 
-----------------------------------------
1    AIE9348ietjg    90.35         458.32
2    Po328gieijge    30.12         87.15
2    AIE9348ietjg    173.12        345.35
```

This table has no ID or other fluff to help condense my example. There may be multiple connect/disconnect records for multiple players in this table. What I want to do is add to my existing AvgTime for each SID these new values.

There is a formula from here I am trying to use (taken from this math stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153794/adding-to-an-average-without-unknown-total-sum/1153800#1153800)

Average = (Average * Size + NewValue) / Size + 1

How can I write an update query to update each ServerIDs traffic table above, and add to the average using the above formula for each pair of records. I tried something like the following but it didn't work (returned back null):

```
UPDATE server_traffic st
LEFT JOIN connect_log l
    ON st.SID = l.SID AND st.UCID = l.UCID
    SET AvgTime = (AvgTime * NumConnects + SUM(l.DisconnectTime - l.ConnectTime) / NumConnects + COUNT(l.UCID)
```

I would prefer an answer in MySql, but I'll accept MS SQL as well.

**EDIT**

I understand that statistics and calculations are generally not to be stored in tables and that you can run reports that would crunch the numbers for you. My requirement is that users can go to a website and view the popularity of various servers. This needs to be done in a way that

A: running a complex query per user doesn't crash or slow down the system

B: the page returns the data within a few seconds at most

See this example here: https://bf4stats.com/pc/shinku555555

This is a web page for battlefield 4 stats - notice that the load is almost near instant for this player, and I get back a load of statistics without waiting for some complex report query to return the data. I'm assuming they store these calculations in preprocessed tables where the webpage just needs to do a simple select to return back the values. That's the same approach I want to take with my Database and Web Application design.

Sorry if this is off topic to the original question - but hopefully this adds additional context that helps people understand my needs.

Comment: can you also add the expected output after `update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot run aggregate functions like `SUM` and `COUNT` by themselves at the unit level in SQL but contained in an aggregate query, consider joining to an aggregate subquery for the `UPDATE...LEFT JOIN`. Also, adjust parentheses in `SET` to match above formula.

Also, note that since you use `LEFT JOIN`, rows with non-match IDs will render `NULL` for aggregate fields and this entity cannot be used in arithmetic operations and will return `NULL`. You can convert to zero with `IFNULL()` but may fail with formula's division.

```
UPDATE server_traffic s
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT SID, UCID, COUNT(UCID) As GrpCount, 
          SUM(DisconnectTime - ConnectTime) AS SumTimeDiff
   FROM connect_log
   GROUP BY SID, UCID) l
ON s.SID = l.SID AND s.UCID = l.UCID

SET s.AvgTime = (s.AvgTime * s.NumConnects + l.SumTimeDiff) / s.NumConnects + l.GrpCount
```

*Aside - reconsider saving calculations/statistics within tables as they can always be run by queries even by timestamps. Ideally, database tables should store raw values.*

Comment: Your answer is good but might take more time to yield the result if so many users have connected to different servers. Would it not be better to calculate `SumTimeDiff` and `GrpCount` from `connect_log` in time intervals on the `DisconnectTime` depending on the periodicity of the job?

Comment: Did you actually test this proposed solution and did it yield your desired result? I cannot answer your design item as you know what you want. What does *time intervals* mean (by nearest hour or minute)? This might be a new question as this intended to fix `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Parfait - The only data I get back from the game is a queue of events indicating when a player connected, and when they disconnected (limitation of the API) that I funnel back into a raw event_log table. This table can explode in size after just a few weeks of use, and re-running stats like these on the entire data set will get more and more performance heavy as more rows are added.

Comment: Then I should re-emphasize last item and underscore the need to NOT store statistics/calculations within tables but run such standalone aggregate queries for reports using such tables.

Comment: @Parfait mind you I need to apply similar logic like this to another event_log table consisting of game events (which will be much much larger in size). A previous database design I saw for this showed the game event table explode to a million rows after just 6 months from 1 server being online. So I need to calculate segments at a time and then backup the raw data so that the main tables are not impacted.

Comment: @Parfait - the problem I have with running a report is that the report will take a very long time to complete, and this is something that is to be displayed on a website for users to see. Running a report on raw queue of events will take an extremely long time (and worse if multiple users are viewing the page) and the page needs to load very quickly to display server traffic data.

Comment: Once again, I believe we are straying from the programming SQL question regarding your `UPDATE` query to a database design question. I do not know your infrastructure or implementation. MySQL can very well scale and handle millions of rows of data. Consult your DBA or ask such a design question in: https://dba.stackexchange.com/. You may be able to partition, add various indices, even backup daily such reports. As for your SQL question, future readers can gain from it.

Comment: @Parfait what I meant by *time intervals* in other word is pagination based on the `DisconnectTime`.

Comment: @Parfait thank you for the answer, it works perfect. I asked the design related question here in case you are interested in providing your thoughts: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194640/database-design-fast-report-execution-on-a-web-site